# Number of threads defined by input

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.scanner

I must create a few threads and do some operations inside them. How to create them using Scanner? E.g. my input is '5' and program creates 5 threads to work with.

Here's my code:

```
public class MyClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Give me a");
      int a = input.nextInt();
      int[] array = new int[a];

      System.out.println("Give me b");
      int b = input.nextInt();

     for(int counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++) {
         System.out.println("Give me a number");
         array[counter] = input.nextInt();
     }

     for(int counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++) {
         System.out.println(array[counter] + " * " + b + " = " + (array[counter] * b));
     }
  }
}
```

I want to modify this code by applying threads. Number of threads should be equal to `a` value given by user. Each thread should make an operation of multiplying a number by `b`.

Comment: why dont you try some coding? before posting a question here

Comment: I had tried some coding, but didn't add here. Look at this now please.

Answer (score 0):

Take the input; say you got N=5. Do a loop from 1 to N,
and start a `Thread` in each iteration of your loop.

Comment: Thanks. How can this be applied to the code I wrote to this moment?